# Files showing Lock symbol Elementary OS Juno

Tags: release-juno, files, permissions

Noob here, I installed Elementary OS Juno at first nothing happened but after a few days somehow the files permission changed to read only
[image]

Comment: Is any other OS besides elementary OS installed on your PC? What is the full address where the locked folders are stored?

Comment: @a-tokarev yes I have dual booted Windows + elementary,

Comment: @a-tokarev it's media/user/disk

Comment: Is your `media/user/disk` folder located on the same partition as your Windows 10 installation?

Comment: I have the same issue with all my files and folders.
I have Windows 10 installed on a separate partition.
It may have happened after I installed a printer.
If I connect a pendrive the files and folders on it can be edited.
Did you find a solution ?

Comment: This problem is caused by Microsoft's fast-startup or Hibernation. If you log into Windows and press reboot or disable fast-startup you will be able to acess those files without any problem. This issue will happen on all partitions that windows loads.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off fast boot inside power management in Windows.